# Excel - How do I calculate sum of products bought in a period of time based on X lead days

Tags: excel

I am creating a formula to try yo find the total amount in pounds that is in in-transit. The current lead time is 5 days. But I have placed a manual override where we could change the lead time to 10 days for example. How do I get it to change outcome to be similar to the 2nd picture below.

the equation in the first white cell is the following
=SUM(OFFSET(B1,0,0,5))
where 5 is the default lead time, but I would like to have that change depending on whether there is a value in the  lead-times override (Final Column)

This equation is dragged down to the remaining white cells in this table so that the last white cell is
=SUM(OFFSET(B12,0,0,5))

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isV58.png)

This is what I want it to look like

[Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3dFU.png)

Sorry if I am unclear in my question since, it is a bit hard to explain in writing.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value exists and use it. If not, fall back to 5.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B1,0,0,IF(NOT(ISBLANK($C$9)), $C$9, 5)))
```

Don't forget to make the override cell static (with the dollar signs) or they will shift when dragging your formula.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Sorry I didn't know any other way to post pictures.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791990/20769999